# Ad field to user in angular firestore / firebase

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

When using angular firestore to log in with email and password, a user object is set to the local storage in the auth.service. There are 5 fields set for that user. I want to add an additional field called "designer", which is a boolean. However, I keep getting an error that I attempted to set the field with a value of "undefined".

I can't figure out how to change this so that the additional "designer" field is returned as part of the result.user. Maybe there is another way.

Auth.Service

```
// Sign in with email/password
SignIn(email, password) {
  return this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['profile']);
      });
      this.SetUserData(result.user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error.message)
    })
}


SetUserData(user) {
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
  const userData: User = {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoURL: user.photoURL,
    emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    designer:user.designer
  }
  return userRef.set(userData, {
    merge: true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried update

```
 SetUserData(user) {
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
  const userData: User = {
   uid: user.uid,
   email: user.email,
   displayName: user.displayName,
   photoURL: user.photoURL,
   emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
   esigner:user.designer
 }
 return userRef.update({...userData}) //here
}
```

Comment: Returns essentially the same error. Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field designer)

Comment: No luck. Same error. The object used to set the userData object in the SetUserData function comes from the function input. I think that something about the return value from the sign in function has to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
return userRef.set(userData, {
merge: (merge === 'true')
 })
```

Comment: Same error. Not sure that it can be fixed in the SetUserData function